# Missing button while executing first official Android tutorial

Tags: android

I am following [official Android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#Button), but when I start the application, I obtain

[image]

instead of getting

[image: button]

Hereunder main files of the sample project

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">AndroidTest</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>


</resources>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.androidtest.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edit_message" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.androidtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**System details**:

- Fedora 20;
- Android 4.4.4;
- Eclipse 4.4;
- ADB

Comment: It isn't buggy. It's just a bad misunderstanding when you chose "Empty Activity" instead of "Blank Activity" when you create the project. Hence, it will have different setup and may break the tutorial flow. From [the official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html#Eclipse), *"For this project, select BlankActivity and click Next."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you never attach the fragment into the activity.

Try to copy the `fragment_main.xml` into `activity_main.xml`!

Comment: And what about the older content of `activity_main.xml`? Can I erase it?

Comment: Yep. I think you do not attach any fragment to the activity. Only the activity_main.xml's content is shown. And that's a textbox. If you want to attach a fragment, create a fragment class, and attach it to the activity. Here's an example: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example

Comment: So the tutorial is buggy if it does not introduce the user to the fragment handling and tries to make him run applications withtout a proper fragment configuration.

Comment: Yep, it's possible. I did not found any good beginner tutorial for Android. :-\

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to add the fragment to the main activity.

There you can see how:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

You must add to your main activity layout, in the place where you want to place fragment.

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.android.MainFragment"
          android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Then you had to create the class of the fragment, and inflate the main activity with the main layout

Comment: So the tutorial is buggy if it does not introduce the user to the fragment handling and tries to make him run applications withtout a proper fragment configuration.